# iOS - Force device orientation, if view controller is presented modally

Tags: ios, swift2, uiinterfaceorientation

ViewControllerA presents ViewControllerB modally.

ViewControllerA should be Portrait orientation.

ViewControllerB should be LandscapeRight orientation.

I do:
**ViewControllerA**:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
    }
```

**ViewControllerB**

```
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight
    }
```

It's works, but when i close ViewControllerB, ViewControllerA becomes also LandscapeRight.
How to fix it? 
Thx.

**SOLUTION**:

Edit AppDelegete file.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is ViewControllerB {

            let secondController = self.window!.rootViewController!.presentedViewController as! ViewControllerB

            if secondController.isPresented {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight;
            } else {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
            }
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is right, but it will get really complicated if you will have more ViewControllers in different orientations. You can try my solution, it is working in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow autorotation in **ViewControllerA** because it needs to go back to Portrait Mode after **ViewControllerB** dismissal. It won't autorotate later on, because you allow only Portrait orientation on this screen.

The solution is:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: @phnmnn Are you using `UINavigationController` in between? Or it's just `UIViewController`?

Comment: UINavigationController

Comment: Well, this changes everything, and your code is not showing the real scenario. When you present something on `UINavigationController` it takes the responsibility for orientation changes and you need to create your own `UINavigationController` or implement the delegate for the current one.